# PHP group mysql select by two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have this table in MySQL:

[image: table]

I want to group select results by browser and version.

**Wanted output:**

```
Array
(
    [firefox 3.0] => 2
    [chrome 24.0] => 1
    [ie 9.0] => 2
    [ie 10.0] => 1
)
```

**Question:** How to group select to get wanted output?

*Note: Table can contain more versions of browsers, so array will expand.*

**My try:**

**PHP:**

```
public function get_browsers() {
    $query = "
        SELECT browser, COUNT(browser) AS num 
        FROM table
        GROUP BY browser 
        ORDER BY browser ASC
        ";
    $select = mysqli_query($this->c, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $data[$row['browser']] = (int) $row['num'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

**Current output:**

```
Array
(
    [firefox] => 2
    [chrome] => 1
    [ie] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function get_browsers() {
    $query = '
        SELECT   browser, version, COUNT(*) AS num 
        FROM     table
        GROUP BY browser, version
    ';
    $select = mysqli_query($this->c, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
        $data[$row['browser'].' '.$row['version']] = (int) $row['num'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT concat(browser," ", version) as browser, COUNT(browser) AS num 
        FROM table
        GROUP BY browser, version 
        ORDER BY browser ASC
```

The trick is to add the `version` as group criteria ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT browser, CONCAT('browser', 'version') as bv COUNT(browser) AS num 
        FROM table
        GROUP BY bv 
        ORDER BY browser ASC
        ";
```

Comment: this would output the string `browserversion` for each `bv` entry